# How to intuitivly think of graphing a function in $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

How to intuitivly think of graphing a function in $\mathbb R^3$?

Let there be $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ $$f(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
        \cos(t) \\
        \sin(t) \\
        t \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Graph $f$. How do I even think about it? I thought that it's a cylinder with made of unit circles at different levels of $t$, but that doesn't seem right anymore...

Also, just a question about a term: What's a parameterized curve and what is it different from other curves?

Thanks!

Comment: Your $f$ is a parametrized curve. =) If you defined $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ then you'd have a surface. Functions as $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are also surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pair $\begin{bmatrix} \cos t \\  \sin t\end{bmatrix}$ just goes around in a circle.  If you think of that circle as being in a horizontal plane, then $t$ is the height above that plane.  So the height steadily increases as the point goes around a circle.  You've seen that as an architectural element.

A parametrized curve is a curve with each point of which a number, called the parameter, is associated.  So as that number changes, the point on the curve moves.  In your example, $t$ is the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a cylinder if we had two variables, so $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$, since then we can let:

$f(t,\theta) = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),t)$ for say $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, $0\leq t \leq 1$

But since we only have one variable to work with, as $t$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$, the $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ perform a full rotation, making our graph a spiral.